# Populating KendoGrid with JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, kendo-ui

Being very new to Kendo UI and Knockout (3 days!), I'm trying to convert a legacy Java applet to Javascript. So far, creating and binding the kendoGrid was relatively easy:

function JobViewModel() {
    var self = this;

```
self.jobData = new ko.observableArray([]);

self.grdJobs = {
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: false,
    columnMenu: true,
    resizable: true,
    columns: [
        { title: "Job ID", field: "jobID" },
        { title: "Owner", field: "owner" },
        { title: "Description", field: "description" },
        { title: "State", field: "runState" },
        { title: "Start Time", field: "timeStart" },
        { title: "End Time", field: "timeEnd" },
        { title: "Elapsed Time", field: "timeElapsed" },
        { title: "Progress", field: "progress" },
        { title: "Agent", field: "agent" },
        { title: "Last Action", field: "lastAction" }
    ],
    selectable: "single"
};
```

};

The data coming back from the server are an array of JSON objects (of any length) something like the following (shortened for brevity):

[{0: 1, 2: 3, 4: 5, ...}, {0: 1, 2: 21, 4: 5, ...}, {0: 1, 2: 23, 4: 5, ...}]

This array of objects which are numeric key/value pairs are mapped to a dictionary object where the numeric keys are paired with string values something like:

{
0: "State"
1: "Finished"
2: "JOB ID"
3: "54759"
4: "Owner"
5: "John"
...
21: "54758"
...
23: "54757"
...
}

What I need to get is the mapped strings from the dictionary as they relate to the array of JSON objects. The approach I tried was to JSON.stringify(obj[i]) but then I wasn't sure what I could do with it (maybe use it in a ko.observable that could be assigned to the kendoGrid?) Anyway, what I'm after based on the sample data I've shown above is a grid with column headers "JOB ID", "Owner", and "State" and 3 rows of jobs (54757, 54758, 54759) all owned by John and State Finished.

I hope this all made sense. I guess what I really need is how to take JSON and convert it into something usable that can be populated into a Kendo Grid. Thanks for helping out a JS/JSON/Kendo/Knockout neophyte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to map those two arrays you have to another array with elements you can use.

I made a simple jsFiddle to demonstrate this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heBym/)

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
var data = [{ 0: 1, 2: 3 }, { 0: 4, 2: 3 }];
var mapping = { 0: 'State', 1: 'Finished', 2: 'Owner', 3: 'John', 4: 'Pending' };

var realData = [];
$.each(data, function(index, obj) {
    var arrayElem = {};
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        arrayElem[mapping[key]] = mapping[value];
    });
    realData.push(arrayElem);
});
```

Comment: That definitely helped. My data and mapping is a little more complicated in that I'll never know how long the data object array is or even how many fields in the mapping object but it's a step in the right direction. Thanks so much for your help!